# CORS issue connecting to Ionic Deploy

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I have setup Ionic Deploy and am receiving the following error that is preventing android from pulling updates

```
 Access to fetch at 'https://api.ionicjs.com/apps/--app-id=REMOVED%20/channels/check-device' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Ionic Info

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.2.1 )
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.9.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.3.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 3.1.2, (and 11 other plugins)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's been a while and no answers given below understand the specific question. I'm getting the same problem -- did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

At server side where you have your API `api.ionicjs.com` deployed, you need to enable CORs header components:

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin
>   
> Access-Control-Allow-Methods
>   
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers

I am not sure about your server side tech stack, so can't suggest where to add this config changes, but sure little googling will find you step by step setup.

Comment: Ionicjs. Is Ionic’s domain and part of ionic deploy and the plugin

Answer (score 0):

this is a server side issue so you have to resolve it from your server end, if you don't know how to enable CORS on your server then you must read this.
https://enable-cors.org/
there are some guidelines about to enable cors for every kind of servers. so no matter what server you are using, you have in it.